# Assumption that time evolution operator first order in $dt$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, calculus, time-evolution

I'm having some trouble with this part of Sakurai's derivation of the time evolution operator in QM (page 70):

> Because of continuity, the infinitesimal time-evolution operator must reduce to the identity operator as $dt$ goes to zero, $$\lim_{dt \to 0} \mathscr{U}(t_0+dt,t_0)=1,$$ and as in the translation case, we expect the difference between $\mathscr{U}(t_0+dt,t_0)$ and 1 to be of first order in $dt$.

(The same argument is made for the translation operator, but no further explanation given.) How does this limit imply that $\mathscr{U}$ must be first order in $dt$? Surely terms of higher order in $dt$ would also reduce to zero in the limit, or are there other considerations at work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms of higher order in $dt$ would reduce to zero faster. What the author says effectively is that the operator is continuous at $t_0$, and can be expanded in Taylor series in $dt$ up to the first order. The smaller is $dt$, the more precise is the expansion, the following results become exact in the limit $dt\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The text doesn't say that $\mathcal{U}$ must be first order in $dt$. It says that $\mathcal{U}(t_0+dt,t_0)-1$ must be first order in $dt$.

Suppose that $\mathcal{U}(t_0+dt,t_0)-1$ has a Taylor series expansion in $dt$ so that
$$\mathcal{U}(t_0+dt,t_0)-1 = \mathcal{U}_0 + \mathcal{U}_1 dt+\mathcal{U}_2 (dt)^2+\dots $$
If we take the limit as $dt\rightarrow 0$ on both sides of this equation we get
$$1-1 = \mathcal{U}_0+0+0+\dots$$
Therefore $\mathcal{U}_0 = 0$ and so
$$\mathcal{U}(t_0+dt,t_0)-1 =  \mathcal{U}_1 dt+\mathcal{U}_2 (dt)^2+\dots $$.
This is what it means to say that the difference between $\mathcal{U}(t_0+dt,t_0)$ and $1$ is first order in $dt$.